# embedding navbar/tabbar breaks constraints of a normally functional view

Tags: swift, ios8, autolayout, constraints, xcode6.1

I have a simple

### UIViewController that normally works:

1. view.backgroundColor
2. UITextView
3. UIView (as a spacer between the bottom and the textview)
4. constraints to pin textview to the view which in turn is pinned to the bottomlayoutguide
5. tapping textview loads keyboard and the spacer view expands accordingly to avoid the keyboard overlapping my textview

---

```
...
//var memoArea = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 291, 275, 225))
memoArea.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: memoArea, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal,
   toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 275.0))

memoArea.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: memoArea, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 225.0))

self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: memoArea, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: self.view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0))

// var spacer:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(84, 518, 160, 6))
spacer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: spacer, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal,
   toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 160.0))

spacer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: spacer, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 6.0))

self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: spacer, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: self.view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 84.0))

view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
spacer.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
memoArea.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
...
```

---

```
...
func updateBottomLayoutConstraintWithNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
let animationDuration = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSNumber).doubleValue
let keyboardEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
let convertedKeyboardEndFrame = view.convertRect(keyboardEndFrame, fromView: view.window)
let rawAnimationCurve = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as NSNumber).unsignedIntValue << 16
let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptions.init(UInt(rawAnimationCurve))

let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
let height = frame?.size.height
spacerToBottom.constant = CGRectGetMaxY(view.bounds) - CGRectGetMinY(convertedKeyboardEndFrame) - height! - 5

UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0.0, options: .BeginFromCurrentState | animationCurve, animations: {
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
...
```

But, after **adding** either a **tab bar** or a **nav bar** to a view that has normally working constraints,

### 3 things break:

1. the background no longer renders, yielding a black background
2. the textview doesn't register taps i.e. keyboard doesn't load
3. view disregards the bottomlayoutguide. it just shifts my objects up as high as their .Top constraints allow them. the constraints between the textview and uiview are still honored though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

commenting out view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) got rid of all errors.